# Passing arguments as a variable when installing an MSI using Start-Process

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and, of course, trying to learn on the fly for a project- No pressure, right! :-)

I am working on a script to run an MSI package in quiet mode, passing it an activation code as an argument,  that I have to extract from an XML file.

So far, I have everything working except for getting Start-Process to run the MSI with the arguments being passed in a Variable.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$XML_Doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XML_Doc.load('c:\myfolder\Configinfo.XML')
$ActivationID = $XML_Doc.CONFIGINFO.SITEINFO.ACTIVATEID
write-host "Activation Id is: $ActivationID"
$InstallString = "`'/I C:\myfolder\myinstaller.msi akey="+'"'+$ActivationID+'"'''
#$InstallString = "`'/I C:\myfolder\myinstaller.msi akey=`"$($ActivationID)`"'"
write-host "$InstallString"'''
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList  $InstallString  -Wait -NoNewWindow
#Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/I C:\myfolder\myinstaller.msi akey="12345678-abcd-1a1b-x9x1-a1b2c3d4e5f6"' -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Above is the code I am working with now. The last line that is commented out is an activation string that works.

I have verified that $ActivationID is pulling back the correct value, and that $InstallString mirrors the argument list in the commented version of the Start-Process string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (Aside: If the default execution policy is in force, it is pointless to try to change it from inside your script since you can't run the script.)

Comment: Thanks Bill - I figured that out last night and moved that into a batch that will call the script

Answer (score 2):

The `Start-Process` commands aren't necessary. PowerShell is a shell. It can run commands. Just put the commands you want to run directly in the script.

```
msiexec /i "C:\myfolder\myinstaller.msi" "AKEY=$ActivationID"
```

I quoted the parameters to `msiexec.exe` in case any of them contain spaces. PowerShell will automatically expand the `$ActivationID` variable into the string inside the double quotes.

Comment: He's using `-Wait`.  `Start-Process` *is* necessary.

Comment: Not correct. Running commands like that block automatically, just like in `cmd.exe`. Give it a try.

Comment: It looks like you're absolutely correct.  If you can edit, I'll remove my vote.  A quick Q, though, if you dot-source (`. msiexec`), is it functionally the same?  I know invoke `&` launches in a different session which causes the disconnect in script flow

Comment: No, `&` does not launch a different session. It is the call (or invocation) operator -- merely a means to execute a string as a command (see `help about_Operators`). In other words, if you need to execute a command in a directory that contains spaces, you need to use the `&` operator (otherwise it's not needed). `&` is not equivalent to `Invoke-Command` or `Invoke-Expression`.

Comment: But doesn't `&` cause it to become asynchronous with the rest of the script?

Comment: No it doesn't. `&` is an operator (see `help about_Operators`).

Answer (score 0):

First off, let me welcome you to Powershell!  It's a great language and a great community gathered around a common cause.

Since you're new to the language, you can still learn new tricks and that's a good thing, because it's generally accepted that the Write-Host cmdlet is nearly always a poor choice.  If you don't trust me, you should trust [the inventor of Powershell](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/).

Now that that's out of the way, we should look at your MSI command.  With Powershell, we don't have to directly open msiexec, and we can call the MSI directly.  I would break the path to the installer into its own variable, and then we can add all of our arguments on top of it.  Also, don't forget the "/qn" switch which will actually make all of this silent.  All in all, your new script will look something like this:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$XML_Doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$XML_Doc.load('c:\myfolder\Configinfo.XML')
$ActivationID = $XML_Doc.CONFIGINFO.SITEINFO.ACTIVATEID
Write-Verbose "Activation Id is: $ActivationID"
$msipath = "C:\myfolder\myinstaller.msi"
$args = @("akey=$ActivationID", "/qn")
Write-Verbose "Install path is $msipath"
Write-Verbose "Activation key is $akey"
Start-Process $msipath -ArgumentList  $args -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

Comment: You're passing the argument list incorrectly.  It will not interpret those properly.

Comment: Ah you're right - on first draft I was just going to use `&` to call the msi, didn't fix with the argument list.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @Bryce Tried the above and now I am getting a "This command cannot be run due to the error: %1 is not a valid win32 application"

Comment: Hmm - is there a space in your path?  You may need to surround it with quotation marks to be passed correctly.  Also, I think I may have put the activation ID in incorrectly - you may need to surround it with quotation marks and use the backtick key to escape the characters to ensure the quotes are transferred into the $args array.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ArgumentList` is being passed incorrectly.

```
[Xml]$XML_Doc = Get-Content -Path 'C:\myfolder\Configinfo.xml'

$ActivationID = $XML_Doc.CONFIGINFO.SITEINFO.ACTIVATEID
Write-Host "Activation Id is: $ActivationID"

$Path = 'msiexec'
$ArgList = @('/i','"C:\path\file.msi"',"akey=`"$ActivationID`"")
Write-Host "$Path $ArgList"

Start-Process -FilePath $Path -ArgumentList $ArgList -Wait -NoNewWindow
```